# Neural Networks for SAT - Clause representation

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, sat

I try to solve [SAT Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) in particular 3-SAT. My dataset is from [SATLIB](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html) and I use [Neuroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) to create Neural Network. In my data set a phrase's clauses are represented like:

```
 1 -2 0
 2  3 0
-3  2 0
```

where **0** - end of clause, **{1,2,3}** - variables, **"-"(minus sign)** - negation. A.k.a. this is equal to:

```
(a^(not)b)v(b^b)v((not)c^b)
```

My problem is that don't know how to represent this like input for Neural Network. On base of this answer I will choose properly input nodes that I need.

P.S: I don't know is it important but NN output must be answer of "Can the phrase be satisfied?".

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the motivation behind this? This doesn't look like a particularly good use-case of NNs to me.

Comment: NNs can be used for classifications (in this case Yes / No) and that is where the idea comes from. Actually that's my idea for a project for Artificial Intelligence course at the university.

Comment: `I highly recommend researching the basics a bit. NN-optimization is all about *smoothness* and being *unconstrained optimization*. Both are invalidated in this case (and as worse as it gets one could say). Without some embedding into a smooth unconstrained surface, there is not much you can do. Maybe that could be based on the same ideas coming from statistical-physics (keyword: message-passing; in CS also known as belief-propagation), but this is highly connected to theory and will be far away from your usual NN usages. I'm somewhat trying to warn you not to jump in blindly into this task!

Comment: Also, your logical formula is wrong: it has to be `(a v !b) ^ ...` instead of `(a ^ !b) v ...`. So it is exactly the other way around!